# How to iterate over a variable that can be both integer and array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, int

I'd like to make a multi-purpose function accepting both integer, and array of integers, like how e.g. some Numpy function like [delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html#numpy.delete) does:

```
def foo(bar):   # type(foo) can be integer or an array of integers
    for i in bar:
        print(bar)
```

The problem is when `bar` is a single `int`, this obivously raises a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. And I couldn't find how to convert `bar` to an array, or anything iterable, in a way that doesn't break the code when `bar` is an array. How to do this?

Comment: First, you check if foo is int: `type(foo)==int`.  Then, if it is, make it an iterable: `foo=[foo]`

Comment: @wolfrevokcats Yeah, but I'd think there surely is some built-in (libary) for converting `2` to `[2]` aren't there? It just seems so basic. Or is it because I'm doing Bad Practite™?

Comment: Well, numpy itself uses `numpy.asarray(obj)` to convert input to ndarray, which is an iterable. Is that what you've been looking for?

Comment: Sorry, a typo: `numpy.core.numeric.asarray(obj)`

Comment: @wolfrevokcats Yeah, something like that. And I already use numpy anyway, so it'll be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) has an optional `ndmin` parameter. Set this to 1 to guarantee you are iterating a 1d array:

```
def foo(bar):   # type(bar) can be integer or an array of integers
    for i in np.array(bar, ndmin=1):
        print(i)
```

You can also specify `copy=False` to avoid a copy being produced if the input is already an array.

Note I have also amended your logic: you want to print `i` rather than `bar` when you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numpy functions `atleast_1d` and `atleast_2d` to get your input with a minimum number of dimensions:

```
>>> atleast_1d(3)
array([3])

>>> atleast_2d(3)
array([[3]])

>>> atleast_1d(randn(1,1))
array([[-0.97860085]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(bar):
    if np.isscalar(bar):
        bar = np.array([bar])
    for i in bar:
        print(bar)
```

You can try this